# Help with adding conditional title tags to header.php

Tags: conditional-tags

From an SEO perspective, i'm trying to add conditional title tags to my WP theme such that it echos a piece of text based on various categories.

Assuming that my category id's are 1, 2, 3, 4

Then i'd like to add Title 1 if category id = 1, title 2 if category id = 2 and so on.

Could someone assist in the correct php syntax to implement this.

Thanks.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, when user is viewing post that's in category with id = 1 you want to echo some specific title?

Comment: Yep. If Category 1 (which is let's call it news) is clicked on, then the title would show "This is the news category" (without the quotes of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See codex page for category conditional tags - http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Category_Page

You can use them like so:

```
<title>
<?php 
if ( is_category( '1' ) )
   echo 'This is the news category';
?>
</title>
```